# Question about the registers of an ADC

Tags: adc, register

There are two things that confuses me in the below text:

"The ADC uses the successive-approximation method to perform the
conversion.The HCS12 uses two 8-bit registers to hold a ananlog to digital conversion result. The result can be stored either right- or left-justified. The A/D conversion is performed in a sequence from one to eight samples."

1- I always thought that registers are storage locations in the CPU. So ADCs would have their own registers too?

2- What are the functionality and meaning of the right- or left-justified registers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I always thought that registers are storage locations in the CPU. So
>   ADCs would have their own registers too?

Registers can be storage locations in any device. You'll find the in ADCs, accelerometers, EEPROMs, etc.

> What are the functionality and meaning of the right- or left-justified
>   registers?

This implies that the result is less than the 16 bits allocated to it. Suppose the ADC produces a 12 bit result. In the left justified case, it would be shifted to the so the MSB is in the MSB of the 16 bit space, like so:

```
16         |3|2|1|0
MSB|...|LSB|X|X|X|X
```

Right justified is the reverse, where the LSB is in the LSB of the 16 bit space.

```
16|15|14|13|12 |   |0
X | X| X| X|MSB|...|LSB
```

Comment: Thank you. So can I ask another question?..in the three registers of right-justified unsigned, left-justified
signed, and left-justified unsigned.What role unsigned and signed part play?

Comment: Unsigned is straight binary. Signed will be 2's complement, sign extended, so the don't care bits become sign extension.

Answer (score 1):

1 - The ADC is given a spot in the same memory the CPU uses to park its result. It isn't a separate chunk of memory. Same memory, reserved location.
2 - In an 8 bit CPU, memory comes in groups of 8 bits. I presume your ADC is 10 or 12 bit? Thus, it is greater than 8 bits but less than 16. The micro gives you the choice it should put the ADC results towards the left or right of those 16 bits. For example, for a 12 bit ADC: left justified will use bits 15-4. Right justified will use bits 11-0.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the ADC is 10 bit. So is there a preference between right justified and left justified? SO ADC chip does not have any memory within and the output is stored in CPU?

Comment: I've always preferred right justified since it seems more intuitive to just truncate the extra bits that arent used. Though most of the MCUs I've used default to left justified, so I assume there is some advantage. Perhaps someone else can speak to that.

Comment: @JustinTrzeciak Have you got that round the wrong way (in your comment, not your answer): right justified means the 'overflow' bits are the MSBs, left justified allows truncation of the LSBs.

Comment: I think I just used the word truncate incorrectly then. For a 12 bit result, I like being able to do this: result = ADCRESULT & 0x0FFF

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, I misinterpreted what you said. I think left-justified is 'default' because it allows the user to opt for an 8-bit result without having to shift any bits. However, this only applies to low-level/assembly programming where all instructions are one register at a time.

Comment: @JustinTrzeciak having left justified means that you could use different systems with different numbers of bits, eg a 16 bit ADC would fill all the bits, an 8 bit one would fill the top 8 bits and stuff zero's in the bottom 8 bits, but could still be read as if it was a 16 bit result, no scaling required, but (obviously) with less resolution.